# Content inside md-card spilling over despite having layout-wrap in its parent tag

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Part of my html file below:

```
<md-content class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-wrap>
            <md-card flex="30" ng-repeat="classified in classifieds" class="classified">
                <img src={{classified.image}} class="md-avatar"></img>
                <md-card-content>
                    <div class="classified-info" ng-hide="showContact">
                        <h2 class="md-title">{{classified.title}}</h2>
                        <h3>{{classified.price | currency}}</h3>
                        <p>{{classified.description}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="classfied-contact" ng-show="showContact">
                        <p><md-icon class="mdi mdi-account"></md-icon>{{classified.contact.name}}</p>
                        <p><md-icon class="mdi mdi-phone"></md-icon>{{classified.contact.phone}}</p>
                        <p><md-icon class="mdi mdi-account"></md-icon>{{classified.contact.email}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <div layout="row">
                        <md-button ng-hide="showContact" ng-click="showContact=true">Contact</md-button>
                        <md-button ng-show="showContact" ng-click="showContact=false">Details</md-button>
                        <md-button ng-hide="showAdmin" ng-click="showAdmin=true">Admin</md-button>
                        <md-button ng-show="showAdmin" ng-click="showAdmin=false">Close</md-button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="classified-admin" ng-if="showAdmin">
                        <h3>Admin</h3>
                        <div layout="row">
                            <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="editClassifieds(classified)">Edit</md-button>
                            <md-button class="md-warn">Delete</md-button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </md-card-content>
            </md-card>
        </md-content>
```

Despite having layout-wrap in my md-content tag, I have some content of the card spilling over when I click on an expanding button inside it(see below image):
[image]

Comment: try to post issue on jsfiddle or something, it will be much easier to debug, this is a css issue so it would be helpful, like this it's almost impossible to debug.

Comment: There is no css associated with it. There is only the code that I have written above.

Comment: Yeah maybe you didn't put any styling on your specific elements, but angular material design has it's own styles, and when you put that on top of your styles you can get errors like yours, so I'm pretty sure that your problem is in CSS, if you want help put entire code, or part of it that reproduces the problem.

Comment: i have put the part of code that creates the md-card and displays it in the site above. Thats what the above code does. You want all the code for the html file?